# How to run CompletableFutures of type boolean in parallel and exit on the first FALSE result or return when all tasks return TRUE?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

So I have a use case where i have four tasks A,B,C,D which i want to run in parallel. the response type of these tasks is boolean.

After running them in parallel, i want to stop the execution on either of the below condition

1. return on receiving first false from any one of the task.
2. All of the 4 tasks are completed and none of them returned false.

my project is using Java, springboot

so i'm trying to use completable futures to achieve this. I could succeed in the first step with something like the below code. but not the second step. any help?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


public class CompFutu {
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> firstMatchingCondition(
            List<? extends CompletionStage<? extends T>> work,
            Predicate<? super T> successFullResultCondition) {

        CompletableFuture<T> result = new CompletableFuture<>();

        Consumer<T> tester = workUnit -> {
            if (successFullResultCondition.test(workUnit)) {
                result.complete(workUnit);
            }
        };

        work.forEach(s -> s.thenAccept(tester));
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> list= Arrays.asList(
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
                    try {
                        System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.err.println("DONE(true 1) "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
                }),
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
                    try {
                        System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        Thread.sleep(20_000);
                        System.err.println("DONE(false 20) "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                }),
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
                    try {
                        System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        System.err.println("DONE(false 5) "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                })
        );

        firstMatchingCondition(list, i->!i).join();

        System.err.println("Done");

    }
}
```

Comment: your failure starts with : "i want to stop the execution on either of the below condition". Once a `CompletableFuture` starts - there is no way to stop it. `CompletableFuture::cancel` with its `mayInterruptIfRunning` flag is very explicit in the documentation about it.

Comment: your `if (successFullResultCondition.test(workUnit))` is going to be executed for _all_ futures. The only reason you think you got it right is because main thread exists early and the VM does not wait for `ForJoinPool` threads to finish their work (which you use under the hood with `supplyAsync`). Of course, such a scenario is a far fetched one in real production.

Answer (score 2):

Create another future that will be completed when all futures have been completed, in addition to your future that will be completed as soon as one fulfills the condition. Then, combine them to a future that will be completed as soon as either of them is completed:

```java
CompletableFuture<?> firstFalse = firstMatchingCondition(list, i -> !i);
CompletableFuture<?> all
    = CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]));

CompletableFuture.anyOf(firstFalse, all).join();
```

You can inline the creations into a single expression.

```java
CompletableFuture.anyOf(
    firstMatchingCondition(list, i -> !i),
    CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
).join();
```

But it’s important to keep in mind that this only affects how long the initiating thread will wait before proceeding. This does not cancel the other futures and since `CompletableFuture` does not support interruption in general, it’s not possible to stop ongoing evaluations anyway. Only their results will be ignored.